# Use a Scala collection method to help convert a list of [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1] into [3,4,2,2]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

So I have a list of 0's and 1's, I want to find the count of each element and output this to a list. I can think of a recursive way to do it with functions but is there any helper functions which can help to convert this?

I believe groupBy could be useful but it seems to group all the elements into one partition or another, not into the way I want.

I want to have a list of the count of numbers until each transition from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. ie, if we have 0,0,0, .. ok we counted 3 zeros so remember 3, then we have 1,1,1,1 so we counted 4 1's, so we remember 4, so far we have a list of [3,4...] and so on

Comment: Ruby has the very useful [Enumerable#chunk](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) for this: `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1].chunk {|e| e }.map(&:last).map(&:size)
# => [3, 4, 2, 2]`. Could be a useful addition to Scala's standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little complicated. but I'd go with it.

```
scala> implicit class ListHelper[A](ls:List[A]) {
         def partitionBy(f: (A, A) => Boolean) = if (ls.isEmpty) List.empty[Int] 
           else (ls zip (ls.head :: ls)).foldLeft(List.empty[Int]){
             case (Nil, _) => List(1)
             case (x :: xs, (a, b)) => if (a == b) (x + 1) :: xs else 1 :: x :: xs
         }.reverse
       }
defined class ListHelper

scala> List(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1).partitionBy(_ == _)
res27: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 2, 2)
```

This is based on the clojure function `partition-by`

Comment: Complicated implementation but simple usage.

Comment: I selected this as the answer as its the one I used, I used it because it's re-usable for other cases.

Answer (score 5):

tail-rec version of Yann Moisan's solution:

```
    def pack[A](ls: Seq[A], prev: Seq[Int] = Seq.empty): Seq[Int] = {
        if (ls.isEmpty) prev
        else {
            val (packed, next) = ls span {_ == ls.head }
            pack(next, prev :+ packed.size)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[Int] = {
  if (ls.isEmpty) List(0)
  else {
    val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
    if (next == Nil) List(packed.size)
    else packed.size :: pack(next)
  }
}
```

Comment: that this can be implemented as tail-recursive function

Comment: This is a useful function, is it included in any Scala library?

Comment: `pack` is not included in the standard library, but it is based on the standard method `span`.

Answer (score 1):

This is groupBy.

```
 val tuple = list.foldRight((0,0)) { (x, accum) =>
     if (x == 0) (accum._1 +1, accum._2) else (accum._1, accum._2 +1) 
 }
 List(tuple._1, tuple._2)
```

on similar lines here is fliptracker (for non-empty lists):

```
def fliptracker(list: List[Int]) = {

    val initial = (list.head, 0, List.empty[Int])

    val result = list.foldLeft(initial) {

        (acc, x) =>

          if (acc._1 == x) (acc._1, acc._2 + 1, acc._3) 
          else (x, 1, acc._3 ::: List(acc._2))
    }

    result._3 ::: List (result._2)
}       

fliptracker(List(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1)) // List(3, 4, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Sorry this is the same as groupBy, I want to have a list of the count of numbers until each transition from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. ie, if we have 0,0,0, .. ok we counted 3 zeros so remember 3, then we have 1,1,1,1 so we counted 4 1's, so we remember 4, so far we have a list of [3,4...] and so on

Comment: ok, please add this example to your question. it was not clear from the text.

Comment: added fliptracker, on similar lines to earlier method.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
List(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1).foldLeft (List.empty[(Any,Int)]) { 
    (acc,a) => acc match {
        case (`a`, occ) :: tail => (a,occ+1) :: tail
        case _                  => (a,1) :: acc
}}.reverse.map(_._2)

res1: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative answer based upon takeWhile. In this 1==black and 0==white

```
case class IndexCount(index: Int, count: Int, black: Boolean)

@tailrec
def takeWhileSwitch(black: Boolean, index:Int, list: List[Boolean], 
        result: List[IndexCount]): List[IndexCount] = {
  if (list == Nil) return result.reverse

  val takenWhile = list.takeWhile(black == _)
  val takenLength = takenWhile.length

  val resultToBuild = if (takenLength != 0) {
    val indexCount = IndexCount(index, takenLength, black)
    indexCount :: result
  } else result

  takeWhileSwitch(!black, index + takenLength, list.drop(takenLength), resultToBuild)
}
val items = takeWhileSwitch(true, 0, rowsWithBlack, List[IndexCount]())
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody expects the imperative solution:

```
def chunk[A](xs: List[A]) = {
  val ys = collection.mutable.Buffer[Int]()
  var prev = xs.head
  var count = 1
  for (x <- xs.tail) {      
    if (x != prev) {
      ys += count
      prev = x
      count = 1
    }
    else count += 1 
  }
  ys += count
  ys.toList
}
```

Comment: Its the same style I used to program when I wrote C and C++ code, but now I try to be functional. For my mind, your solution is very clear and easy to read.